# Error with no hint of problem cause - 'ERROR @wdio/runner: Error'

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I'm getting this error when trying to run Cucumber JS tests inside of the docker container.

**Error log from console inside of a container**

```
2021-09-13T13:25:32.569Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "docker" as NPM package
2021-09-13T13:25:32.593Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2021-09-13T13:25:32.595Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onPrepare" hook in 2ms
2021-09-13T13:25:32.596Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2021-09-13T13:25:32.596Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onWorkerStart" hook in 0ms
2021-09-13T13:25:32.597Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: features/env_Pindstrup/config/wdio.single.conf.js
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:58.891Z WARN @wdio/utils:shim: You are running tests with @wdio/sync which will be discontinued starting Node.js v16.Read more on https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/discussions/6702
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.201Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.261Z DEBUG @wdio/config:utils: Found '@babel/register' package, auto-compiling files with Babel
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.536Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.538Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "docker" as NPM package
[0-3] RUNNING in chrome - /features/env/workAcception.feature
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.858Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.864Z INFO devtools:puppeteer: Initiate new session using the DevTools protocol
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.865Z INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome with flags: --enable-automation --disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-sync --metrics-recording-only --disable-default-apps --mute-audio --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-breakpad --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-fieldtrials=*BackgroundTracing/default/ --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-features=site-per-process,TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1200,900 --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --use-fake-device-for-media-stream
[0-3] 2021-09-13T11:45:59.917Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: 
[0-3]     at new LauncherError (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/utils.ts:31:18)
[0-3]     at new ChromePathNotSetError (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js:33:9)
[0-3]     at Object.linux (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-finder.ts:153:11)
[0-3]     at Function.getFirstInstallation (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-launcher.ts:177:61)
[0-3]     at Launcher.launch (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-launcher.ts:223:37)
[0-3]     at Object.launch (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-launcher.ts:71:18)
[0-3]     at launchChrome (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/devtools/build/launcher.js:72:44)
[0-3]     at Object.launch [as default] (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/devtools/build/launcher.js:172:16)
[0-3]     at Function.newSession (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/devtools/build/index.js:50:49)
[0-3]     at Object.remote (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:67:43)
[0-3]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[0-3]     at Runner._startSession (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:217:56)
[0-3]     at Runner._initSession (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:173:25)
[0-3]     at Runner.run (/var/www/html/onsite-tests-cucumber/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:87:19)
```

I have no idea what kind of a thing is causing this error to appear.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: FIXED!
Problem was in wdio.conf.js file

**runner: 'local',**

TO

**hostname: 'selenium-hub',
port: 4444,
path: '/',**